# rxjs trigger one observable before the other one conditionaly

Tags: javascript, angular, rxjs, angular9

I am seeking for help or a clue for an issue with rxjs that I am not able to solve.

Basically, I want to trigger an observable and complete before the original one trigger.

Case: I am working on a project in which I have two profiles, say `profileA`, `profileB`.
Sometimes `profileA` has some properties that I need to pass to the `profileB` in order to get the `profileB`. And at the end, I combine the both profiles and return the orignal observable.

Usually, I cache the `profileA` in `localStorage` and I can get the `profileB`.

```
getProfileB() {
  const url = `${..}/xyz/${this.profileB.username}/userData`
  return this.http.get(anUrl); // and returns the observale to the next destination 
}
```

But sometimes could be that the `profileA` is not available in the `localstorage`, so in that case, first I have to find fetch the `profileA` and then continue with the `profileB` fetching.

I would like to use the following approch. Since I don't about

```
getProfileA() {
  return this.http.get(anUrlForProfileA);
}

getProfileB() {
  const url = `${..}/xyz/${this.profileB.username}/userData`
  return this.http.get(anUrl).pipe(
    aPipeOperator() => {
    // the null could be the mean that continue with the current Observable, whereas concatenateFirst means, first completes the getProfileA observable and then continue with the original one.
      return this.profileA?.username?.length > 0? concatenateFirst(this.getProfileA()) : null;

     
    }
  ); 
}
```

I am little struggling with the rxjs, and it is also difficult for me to explain, so please help me. This issue could solve me other problems too.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

[Edit]: Since you want to use your `profileA` in your `profileB` request, you should use SwitchMap, [as **Jason Goemaat** said](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71024416/9868549). Here is another example a bit different for a better *beginner comprehension* than his one :

```js
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  ngOnInit() {
    this.getProfileB();
  }
  
  getProfileA(): Observable<{ name: string, profile: string }> {
    return of({ profile: "A", name: 'Quentin' });
  }

  getProfileB() {
    this.getProfileA().pipe(
      switchMap(profileA => {
        // ProfileA is completed, you can acces its value
        console.log(profileA);
        // return another observable (For you, your api call for ProfileB)
        return of({profile: "B", name: "John", profileA});
      }),
    ).subscribe(profileB => {
      // Get profileB value here
      console.log(profileB);
    })
  }
}
```

---

From your example, it looks like you could use [`forkjoin()`](https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/combination/forkjoin). It wait for all the observables to complete before to continue, so you could so something like that:

```js
forkJoin(getProfileA(), this.http.get(anUrlForProfileB)).pipe(
  mergeMap(obs => { //... use obs[0] and obs[1] to access your observable values}
);
```

Comment: the obs in forkjoin are triggered simultaneously, how can I get the ProfileA and wait for the second observable to start in order to pass the data to ProfileBReq, in case I don't have the ProfileA data yet.

Comment: @Phoenix404 I edited my answer to give you an example of how to use `switchMap`. Have a look at Jason Goemaat's answer. Basically, `switchMap` complete the first observable, and emit another one.

Answer (score 1):

I think [switchMap](https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/transformation/switchmap) is what you are looking for.  You pass it a function that will take the result of your observable and return an observable to replace it.

```js
const getProfileA = () => of({ name: 'A' })

const getProfileB = (profileA: any) => {
  const requestProfileB = of({ name: 'B', message: `This is profile B, using data from profile with name '${profileA.name}'`})
  return requestProfileB.pipe(map(profileB => ({ profileA, profileB })))
}

getProfileA().pipe(switchMap(getProfileB)).subscribe(x => console.log(x))
```

Here `getProfileA` mimics an http call to return profile 'A'.  That result is piped into `switchMap` which you pass `getProfileB`.   That function takes profileA and creates `requestProfileB`  using data from profileA.  That is piped to map() which combines the result from the request for profileB with the passed value for profileA into one object that will be emitted when the result is subscribed to.  Result:

```json
{
    "profileA": {
        "name": "A"
    },
    "profileB": {
        "name": "B",
        "message": "This is profile B, using data from profile with name 'A'"
    }
}
```

[CodePen Link](https://codepen.io/JasonGoemaat/pen/mdqRWoq)